# Getting null value while passing value from jsp to jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee

Hi friends I am trying to pass value from one jsp to another by link but the value is not passing. I referred many answers in forums. Nothing helped.

Display.jsp

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%ResultSet resultset =null;%>

<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>Select element drop down box</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY>



<h2>EMPLOYEE DETAILS</h2>
<br>
<form  action = "Form.jsp">
<button type = "submit">Add New Employee</button>
</form>
<%
    try{
           Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

           Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hirarchy_check","root","root@123");

           Statement statement = connection.createStatement() ; 

           resultset =statement.executeQuery(" SELECT e.Emp_Id,e.Emp_Name ,e.Emp_Designation, m.Emp_Designation"+
                  " FROM employee_details e " +
                   " INNER JOIN employee_details m on e.Manager_id = m.Emp_Id ") ;

%>
  <table border = 1>
              <tr><th>Employee Id</th><th>Employee Name</th><th>Employee Designation</th><th>Reporting Manager</th><th>View</th></tr>
              <tr><td>1</td><td>Steve</td><td>ceo</td><td>0</td><td><a href = 'FormUpdate.jsp'>View</a></td></tr>

  <%    
              while(resultset.next())
              { %>
                  <tr><td><%=resultset.getInt(1)%></td><td><%=resultset.getString(2)%></td>
                  <td><%=resultset.getString(3)%></td><td><%=resultset.getString(4)%></td>
                  <td><a href="EmpDetails.jsp?empId=${resultset.getInt(1)}&empName=${resultset.getString(2)}" >update</a></td></tr>
            <%  } %>

    </table>

<%         }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
             out.println(e);
        }
%>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

And the page which I have to pass the value is

EmpDetails.jsp

```
  <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Employee Details</title>
</head>
<body>
out.println<%=request.getParameter("empId") %>
out.println<%=request.getParameter("empName") %>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note**

To run code from below answer, you must include `JSTL` tag library. It can be found [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/jstl/jstl.jar.zip).

Or To Include, write following line on the top of your JSP.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %>
```

**Answer**

Can you please try forEach?

```
<c:forEach var="row" items="${resultset.rows}">
<tr>
<td><a href="EmpDetails.jsp?empId=${row.Emp_Id}&empName=${row.Emp_Name}">update</a></td>
</tr>    
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: I think resultset.getInt(1) doesn't work as you expected and imho, it is more readable with this way.

Comment: The question asker is probably not using JSTL

Comment: Yes i am new to java technologies and programming also @rupinderjeet47

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jsp to jsp redirection just use EL(Expression Language) and put

`${param.empId}` insted of `<%=request.getParameter("empId") %>`

`${param.empName}` insted of `<%=request.getParameter("empName") %>`

You need to do this as you are redirecting from JSP to JSP else not necessary...